# return a Boolean value if at least one of them matches with regexp in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex, where-clause

I have a key called fileName whose value is org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/internal/ketch/ProposalRound.java and I want to return a boolean value if the fileName matches with %/src%. The query looks like

```
SELECT p.id, p_userName,
COUNT(f.id) as NoOfFilesModified, 
sum(f.f_linesInserted) as linesInserted, 
sum(f.f_linesDeleted) as linesDeleted
FROM t_change as c, t_file as f, t_revision as r, t_people as p
WHERE f.f_revisionId = r.id 
AND r.rev_changeId = c.id
AND c.ch_authorAccountId = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.p_userName;
```

The result is obtained as

```
id  p_userName  NoOfFilesModified   linesInserted   linesDeleted
1   spearce     2190                   50102    20117
2   HudsonVoter 397 14272   494
```

I want to add another field which returns 1 or 0 if at least one of the files matches with %/src/%

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

try use subquery like

```
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t_file WHERE f.f_revisionId = r.id AND f.filename REGEXP 'src')
```

or

```
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t_file WHERE f.f_revisionId = r.id AND f.filename LIKE '%src%')
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Probably want `LIKE`, not `REGEXP`.